# How to infer argument type when calling a generic method?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> data)
```

And I am trying to make a call to it by doing:

```
var myVar= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LeagueFixtures>(url);
DataTable myDataTable = ToDataTable(myVar);
```

However I get the error "The types of arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments specifically." on the line where I am calling ToDataTable.

The structure of the LeagueFixtures class is:

```
public class Fixtures
{
    public string leagueName { get; set; }
    public List<LeagueFixtures> fixtures { get; set; }       
}

public class LeagueFixtures
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public int matchday { get; set; }
    public FixtureResult result { get; set; }
}

public class FixtureResult
{
    public int goalsHome { get; set; }
    public int goalsAway { get; set; }
}
```

I could get it to work if I done:

```
var myVar= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Fixtures>(url);
DataTable myDataTable = ToDataTable(myVar.fixtures);
```

but I couldn't access the result by doing myVar.fixtures.result, whereas when going directly to LeagueFixtures I can access result.

Comment: I understood everything until the last sentence. Also, DeserializeObject returns T, it doesn't return List<T>, so you cannot expect it to be assignable to it.

Comment: `ToDataTable` expects a list, but `myVar` is a `LeagueFixtures`.  There is no generic type parameter that will overcome this problem.  If you want to call `ToDataTable`, you need to pass it a list.  I don't understand your last sentence.  What's the problem with `myVar.fixtures`?  It seems like exactly what you want.

Comment: LeagueFixtures is not a List<T> type where as Fixtures.fixtures is a List<LeagueFixtures>.  You cannot pass in LeagueFixtures as a argument for something wanting List<T>.  What exactly is in your JSON data?

Comment: @MikeBurdick the json is in the form : {fixtures: [{date, matchday, result  : {goalsHome, goalsAway}] }

Comment: What is it you expect, _exactly_, for the `ToDataTable()` method to return when you pass it an instance of `LeagueFixtures`? Is the `LeagueFixtures` some kind of collection that would even make sense to represent as a list or a table? As stated, your question is very confusing and unclear.

Comment: @recursive its because I wanted to access results as well but I now realise I cant

Comment: @PeterDuniho Doing `var myVar= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Fixtures>(url);
DataTable myDataTable = ToDataTable(myVar.fixtures);`   was actually correct. I wanted to send the `.result` to `ToDataTable()` but didn't realize this wont work because its not a List, only `LeagueFixtures` is a List. The last part of my question was about sending `.result` to `ToDataTable()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ToDataTable takes a List, and you're trying to pass it an object of type LeagueFixtures (which is what the deserialize method is returning).  You could create a new list to pass into the ToDataTable with the myVar variable:

```
DataTable myDataTable = ToDataTable<LeagueFixtures>(new List<LeagueFixtures>{myVar});
```

Note, the `<LeagueFixtures>` is unnecessary at this point because the type can be inferred.

**Edit**

As to your problem accessing `myVar.fixtures.result` - you can't do that because myVar.fixtures is a `List<LeagueFixtures>` and you need to call `.result` on an object within that List

Comment: Creative approach!  I wonder if this will actually do what is desired.  The resulting DataTable is likely to only have one row.

Comment: @timvinc the code worked but when trying to access result you said I have to call .result on an object within that List. What exactly do you mean by this? Did you mean something like var results = myVar.result;

Comment: If you deserialize myVar as a Fixture calling myVar.fixtures will give you a List<LeagueFixtures> you can't call `.result` on the entire list

Comment: Say you have a Fixture object `fixture`.  you can get a List of LeagueFixtures by calling `fixture.fixtures`   then say you want to get the first LeagueFixture in that List, you can call `fixture.fixtures.First().result` (Assuming that the list has at least one object in it)